# Pass selected value from drop down box in select statement using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have drop down that shows the location name and the data source for the drop down brings both the LOC_NM and LOC_ID but the user will see only the Location Name.  So what I want to do is pass the LOC_ID in my select query, how would I do that?
Here is the code for the drop down:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="locatioin"  DataSourceID="dd_source" DataTextField="LOC_NM" DataValueField="LOC_ID" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select Location" Value="Select Location"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and here is the code behind for my select statement:

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Company, Location from MainTable
    where Location = selected LOC_ID")
```

as you can see i want to pass the LOC ID for the selected value in my query but i am having trouble with that: where Location = selected LOC_ID

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the fast solution:

```
var tmp = "SELECT Company, Location FROM MainTable WHERE LocationColumn = {0}");
var query = string.Format(tmp,location.SelectedValue);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query);
```

This is the safe solution:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
conn.Open();
string s = "SELECT Company, Location " + 
           "FROM MainTable " +
           "WHERE LocationColumn = @location";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@location", location.SelectedValue);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Credit to one of the best coding sites: [Coding Horror: Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Comment: nice answer, but I would always prefer to use the safe solution, rather than fast one.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov programming isn't always about using the safest solution. The purpose describes how safe it should be!

Comment: wegginho, in the MainTable we don't have LOC_NM but we only have LOC_ID so the query filter has to use LOC_ID.  How can we do that?

Comment: @moe According to your definition, you're using the DataValueField="LOC_ID". If that's what you're really doing SelectedValue should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

moe: I hope you are not concatenating SQL strings, like in the example you posted. This kind of concatenating suffers from SQL injection attack. I would suggest to use parametrizied queries.

Regards,
Uroš

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Company, Location from MainTable
    where Location = "+locatioin.SelectedValue+"")
```

you just need to use the `selected value` property of dropdown.

Although you will also need to correct your query.

Comment: 1. I guess its Location and not locatioin
2. Ah you can use SQL and C# all at once in quotation marks?

Comment: @wegginho in the orignal post it is locatioin only